# Unix/Windows/Putty bell or beep utility won't ring | The Unix is Ubuntu server 16.04 SSH Bash

Tags: ssh, putty, sound-card, system-sounds, bell

I use Putty to SSH my remote Ubuntu 16.04 server.

### 1. Putty bell won't ring:

I want to ring the Putty bell and tried the dedicated commands for that:

```
echo -e "\07" && echo -e "\007"
```

When I execute these, no sound is heard when speakers' amplitude is above 25%.

[image]

---

### 2. Beep utility won't ring:

I also tried to do `sudo apt-get install beep && beep`.

Yet, after a successfull installation, I still hear no sound when executing beep.

The speakers' amplitude was the same (above 25%).

---

### 3. Local Unix and Windows bell won't ring:

I tried the aforementioned commands on a Local Ubuntu 14.04 installment, as well as the command `echo ^G` on Win10 CMD... Also in these cases, no bell sound is heard...

---

My question is --- Why would the bell won't ring?

It might be a hardware problem as I know the bell sound is produced by different unit, than those who process common sounds like those of GUIs / Video games / Internet (Youtube) etc.

Yet, I wonder if there is anything I should check before finally concluding it is hardware based? Maybe something in the BIOS or in Windows itself?

---

### Update for pbies:

pbies, as you can see, it seems to be already setted:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed Win10 I went to `Control panel > Sound > Sounds`, and there I muted all system sounds By choosing `Sound scheme > "no sounds"`...

This prevented me from hearing any bell sounds later, as in this time.

---

When I unmuted the system sounds I did heard a beep, both in Putty and local Win-10 based Ubuntu (WSL Ubuntu).

Yet because I usually do not want to hear system sounds I had to search for the particular system sound that will reflect such beeps; One of these I found, and probably the closest of them is "default beep" --- Pick it (or any other suitable sound option) and give it a sound as you like, from the `.wav` sound list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up bell in PuTTy's options.

Comment: I've edited the question with an image that seemingly show it is already setted. Please take a look.

Comment: There can a problem with system bell sound. Try the flash option first. If it works, it seems that the system does not allow sound from PuTTY's terminal.

Comment: The flash effect (for the Putty window) does indeed work for both commands, but still no sound is heard... :\

Comment: BTW I know that beeps are not really processed by the same hardware units working with "regular" sound... Is it true? Maybe you would suggest me of checking something?

Comment: It depends on the system you have. If it is Windows, there should be no problem. But if it is Linux, I have the same problem. And with PuTTY and also standard terminal. So the problem exists somewhere else.

Comment: I found the problem and published an answer below. You guys are welcome to take a look.